# When to use patch files of project 'gproc'?

Tags: erlang

When studying the project 'gproc' source code files, I have found several patch files in the patch directory (for example "kernel.erl, gen_event.erl, gen_fsm.erl,gen.erl, supervisor.erl, sys.erl").
But in the readme file and makefile, there is nothing talking about these files.

Because the erlang runtime version has been updated frequently and now my machine uses R15B. Could you tell me is it necessary for me to patch my runtime? If possible, please give me a little explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The patches exist solely to demonstrate how the application *could* work if it were made an integrated component of Erlang/OTP, so you don't need (or want, probably) to apply them.

Comment: Could you explained "made an integrated component " more clearly?

Comment: [This](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2009-October/047143.html) may offer some insight.